# PowerPoint VBA - Passing Shapes by value seems to be happening by reference

Tags: vba, powerpoint

For part of a VBA script I'm putting together I want to iterate through all the shapes on the current slide and insert another shape on top of each.

I have a first subroutine, GetShapes(), that gets all the shapes on the current slide and then passes them by value to a second subroutine, LabelShapes(), which adds the new shapes on top.

However, the new shapes seem to show up in the Shapes object that was passed.  It seems like this should not be the case as it was passed by reference.

WARNING, the below will quickly lockup PowerPoint

```
Sub GetShapes()
    Dim ss As Shapes
    Set ss = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes
    Call LabelShapes(ss)
End Sub


Sub LabelShapes(ByVal ss As Shapes)
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ss
        Debug.Print s.Name
        Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddShape _
            Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=15, Height:=15

    Next

End Sub
```

I imagine I can get around this by using a special naming convention for my new shapes and then filtering them out.  Maybe there is a better way?  But, really I would just like to understand why this isn't behaving the way I expect.

Comment: I think you need to use the [`ShapeRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange) object

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it's a common misunderstanding that passing object references `ByVal` would magically create a copy of the object.

Passing an object reference `ByVal` means you're passing **a copy *of the object pointer***, as opposed to a *reference* to that very same object pointer.

In both cases, you're passing an object pointer that's pointing to the exact same object, so when you `.AddShape`, you're altering the very same shape collection you're in the middle of iterating.

Passing an object reference `ByVal` does NOT pass a copy of the object. If you want to pass a copy, you need to *make* a copy.

This might help clarify:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = New Collection
    TestByVal obj 'pass a copy of the object reference
    Debug.Assert Not obj Is Nothing
    TestByRef (obj) 'force a copy of the object reference (despite ByRef)
    Debug.Assert Not obj Is Nothing
    TestByRef obj 'pass a reference to the object pointer
    Debug.Assert Not obj Is Nothing ' << assert will fail here
End Sub

Private Sub TestByVal(ByVal obj As Object)
    Set obj = Nothing ' only affects the local copy
End Sub

Private Sub TestByRef(ByRef obj As Object)
    Set obj = Nothing ' DANGER! call site will see this
End Sub
```

Comment: Very clear and precise - you've got a memorable quote there in "If you want to pass a copy, you need to *make* a copy."

Comment: @BigBen thanks - in this case I guess the copy is the `ShapeRange` instance your [excellent as well] answer is alluding to ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for your answer.  It explains the behavior although I'm not clear what the purpose of having the ByRef and ByVal distinction if both ultimately pass a pointer (a ref there to).  I'm going through the code you were kind enough to provide, but am unclear how you are forcing a copy is that what the parens do?  (Also when I run your code, I get a 450 error on the first TestByRef call.)

Comment: @Chris yes, that is *exactly* what the parentheses do - and why you should avoid extraneous parentheses where they're not needed! The reason to pass an object reference `ByRef` or `ByVal` is exactly the same as passing any other value `ByRef` or `ByVal`: use `ByRef` when you mean to alter the pointer/value in the body of the procedure *and have the caller see that updated pointer/value*, or `ByVal` (what you want 99% of the time) when the caller doesn't need or shouldn't see whatever (accidental?) changes could be made to it in the body of the procedure.

Comment: ...the side-effects of this are illustrated by the `Set obj = Nothing` assignment - it's a locally-scoped *copy* of the pointer with `ByVal`, and if you pass it `ByRef` then you get the same pointer *and modifying it will have consequences at the call site*.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the [`ShapeRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange) object, which "represents a shape range, which is a set of shapes on a document."

Note from the [`Shapes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes) documentation:

> If you want to work with a subset of the shapes on a document — for example, to do something to only the AutoShapes on the document or to only the selected shapes — you must construct a ShapeRange collection that contains the shapes you want to work with.

```
Sub GetShapes()
    Dim ss As ShapeRange
    Set ss = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range
    LabelShapes ss
End Sub


Sub LabelShapes(ByVal ss As ShapeRange)
    Dim s As Shape

    For Each s In ss
        Debug.Print s.Name
        Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddShape _
            Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=15, Height:=15

    Next
End Sub
```